# Will we remain permanently in Beta?

Tags: discussion

We've been in Beta for more than three years. If you look at [the area51 page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335) you'll see that we're doing pretty well on most counts. The fly in the ointment remains the amount of new questions. This relates directly to the size of our community. I don't foresee us ever managing to sustain 10 new questions a day.

On the plus side, even with fewer new questions than is normal for a large community, I definitely have the feeling that many of our members keep coming back here and keep up-to-date on what's happening.

Is there any way to persuade the folks at Stack Exchange that we're here to stay, even though this might be as good as it gets?

Answer (score 2):

The Area 51 stats, displayed by severely outdated software, reflect the approach to beta-graduation process from 2010-11. They no longer represent what Stack Exchange considers most important about this process.

Their new approach is described in  [Graduation, site closure, and a clearer outlook on the health of SE sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257614)

> Is there any way to persuade the folks at Stack Exchange that we're here to stay

You have done that already. This is a stable site, which Stack Exchange is happy to host indefinitely. (As far as I know; I do not work for them.) Quote from the post linked above:

> 1. **When a site starts to consistently receive 10 questions/day, we’ll consider it for graduation.**
> 2. **If a public beta site does not produce consistently helpful content, and lacks the caretakers needed for flags and spam to get handled and our Be Nice policy to be upheld, it will be closed.**
>
> Is your site in between these two categories? You don’t have anything to worry about. Regardless of how small the site might be, you have a home here in the SE network. *Spoiler alert: As of this post, no site which is currently active is at risk of being shut down.*

Comment: So if we're here to stay, why do we have to remain in Beta? Beta means your status is unclear.